# Qu'est-ce que « passer par » veut dire ?

Tags: sens, expressions, prépositions

I saw this line in a French TED talk:

> Mon apprentissage de mots français passe par l’écriture.

I can't find the phrase *"passer par"* in a dictionary and by guessing I'd say it means "My learning of French words was *through* writing". Is this correct, and how exactly is this phrase used?

Comment: Just an afterthought from a fellow non-native (please excuse me if you’re not), but “passer par” also seems to have a notion similar (and perhaps translatable) to “to use” in English (e.g., to ‘use’ [passer par] a [particular] door or to ‘use’ [passer par] a lawyer), so maybe you could “use” this notion of “use” to translate your sentence, granted less literally, with a slightly more “active” feel to it: “I **use** writing to learn French words” or “I **am using** writing to learn French words/to increase my French vocabulary.”

Comment: @PapaPoule thank you very much, I am not native and only beginning to learn French, so thank you for the explanation. I knew passe par had a meaning of "go/come do something" but here the usage is so different than what I was able to find online.

Comment: It's a hard sentence to understand & rephrasing it to use “**I/Je** [+ a verb]” helped me to understand it better. I suggested “am using” in my comment, but after reading @comet’s answer, especially the first parenthetical in the last paragraph ("j'ai présentement recours à l'écriture pour d'apprendre des mots," which I’d translate as “I'm now resorting to/relying on writing to learn words), I now think that the verbal phrase “avoir recours à” is the best way to understand “passer par” in this case(but as mentioned in that answer, context is key & its final 2 parentheticals are also possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase can be found in a lot of different cases, for instance, when you give directions to someone. But in most cases, "go through" or "through" is the most appropriate way to translate.

Your sentence is correct, but I wouldn't translate it exactly the same as a French speaker. I think it would be better if you said "My learning of French words is through writing".

A few examples of different contexts :

- *Pour aller à la gare, tu dois passer par la rue Victor Hugo.* "To get to the train station, you have to go through Victor Hugo street"
- *Je suis passé par de multiples opérations pour réparer ma cheville.* "I went through multiple surgeries to fix my ankle"

This expression is a bit hard to translate, I hope the few examples I gave will help you understand the different ways it can be understood depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

It means writing is a **step** to learn french words. The more you write (in french) the more you will learn french words.

If a friend comes home and you don't have anything to eat, you can say to him

- passe par la pizzeria avant de venir chez moi

  what can be said too
- passe acheter une pizza avant de venir chez moi

Here it's a step in the travel.

Comment: Thank you very much! I always understood it in my head as "go/come do something" so this usage threw me off, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

En complément, on a plusieurs éléments de solution au [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/passer/58494/locution?q=passer%20par#158377) et au [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passer) :

> **Passer par**, accéder quelque part en empruntant tel chemin : *Passez par
> la porte de derrière*.
>  **Passer par**, se trouver dans tel état, dans
> telle situation, au cours d'un processus, avoir à subir telle épreuve
> : *Il est passé par toutes les couleurs.*
>  **Passer par** quelqu'un,
> quelque chose (pour), avoir recours à tel intermédiaire, suivre telle
> voie pour aboutir à ce qu'on recherche : *Inutile de passer par lui,
> voyez le directeur. Passer par une agence pour avoir des billets.*
>
> ---
>
> **I.**
>  A. − Aller d'un mouvement continu d'un point à un autre;
> parcourir, traverser un lieu.
>  [...]
> B. − [L'action implique un obstacle à franchir, une difficulté à surmonter; ceux-ci sont désignés ou non]
> 1.
>  a) 
> [...]
>  β) [Avec compl. prép. ou adv. de lieu] 
>  − **Passer par**. *Le* (...) *buffet* (...) *n'est jamais trop grand pour ne pouvoir pas passer par la porte* (Nosban, *Manuel menuisier*, 1857, p.86).
> ♦ Au fig. ***Passer par** (l'intermédiaire de) qqn*; passer par une agence
> de voyage. *Le chef du personnel (...) ne dirige directement qu'un
> petit nombre d'employés, et, pour commander les autres, il doit passer
> par l'intermédiaire de leur chef hiérarchique* (Villemer, Organ.
> industr., 1947, p.252)
> [...]
> **II.** − [La destination est connue]
>  [...]
>  **III**. − [Le mouvement est provisoirement interrompu]
>  A. − [Gén. avec compl.
> prép. ou adv. de lieu] **Qqn passe**
> B. − P. ext. **Qqn/qqc. passe**
> 1.
>  a) Exercer une activité, occuper une fonction, suivre une formation, subir un traitement de façon transitoire.
>  α) [Le
> compl. désigne l'activité] ***Passer par** les affaires*
>  [...]
>  b)
> En partic. **Passer par** (un stade dans une évolution). *Passer par un
> (plusieurs) état(s), par une (plusieurs) étape(s), par une (plusieurs)
> phase(s)*. *Pour arriver à la synthèse, il faut nécessairement passer
> par l'analyse* (Viollet-Le-Duc, *Archit.*, 1863, p.463).
> [...]
>  c) P. anal.
>  α) ***Passer par** (une crise, une épreuve)*.
> Subir (une crise, une épreuve). *Cette démocratie* (...) *avait besoin
> de passer par l'épreuve des affaires* (Gambetta, 1874 ds *Fondateurs
> 3e Républ.*, p.233)
>
> ---
>
> [ Extraits des entrées (*passer*) au *Larousse* en ligne et au *Trésor
> de la langue française informatisé*, respectivement ]

On peut ajouter que tel que présenté en question, il peut s'agir d'une explication (*j'ai présentement recours à l'écriture pour d'apprendre des mots*), mais aussi peut-être, à mon avis, d'un constat au sujet d'une solution à appliquer à un moment futur (*si je veux apprendre davantage de mots, il me faudra écrire... davantage*), ou même d'une forme de résignation face à l'incontournable (*je ne peux absolument pas apprendre de mots si je n'écris pas.*). On peut voir on non ces nuances selon qu'on envisage le tout comme un *processus* en cours, une *épreuve* particulière à surmonter ou une *solution* à appliquer etc. Le contexte fera certainement la différence...